# Accessing a PHP method

Tags: php, database, methods, c#-3.0

I'm about to start working on a project for an organization using C#. In order to get the necessary data I have to get the data from a database, however, I will not be given access to the database even to create the application. As you can assume this creates a bit of a challenge.

In a past project I created a PHP script that accessed a database for me and returned the data in JSON format. I'd like to the same, unfortunately there are around 100-120 queries that I would need to be able to make so it would be very time consuming to create a PHP script for every query that I need.

Is it possible to create a method in PHP that takes in a string argument and then use somehow pass the string into it from C#? If so then how can I do it? If I can pass a string to the method within the script then it would only take 3 methods (in the PHP script) in order to make all the necessary queries.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself here. You need to get data from a database you don't have access to. Where does C# come into the picture here? Please explain the architecture more in detail.

Comment: I'm not contradicting myself at at all. I'm using C# to work with the data once I have received it.

Comment: *Is it possible to create a method in PHP that takes in a string argument and then use somehow pass the string into it from C#?* -- If you can make that make sense, then I think we might get somewhere.

Comment: I want to create a PHP script that contains 3 methods each one requiring a string argument. I want to be able to call each of these methods from C#. Is that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive example of invoking a PHP method from a C# application/library would involve using the `WebRequest` and `WebResponse` classes:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) 
    WebRequest.Create("http://server/script.php?method=my_method");

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Using the stream, you can then parse through or deserialize the response, if it's a JSON string for example.

This implementation relies on `script.php` using the `method` parameter, and delegating the call to that method; pseudo-routing if you will. More arguments can be passed via the query-string, and used by the invoked method.

Another trivial example of this:

```
$r = new Repository();
$d = $r->{$_GET['method']}();
echo json_encode($d);
```

**However**, much of this can be implemented using existing technologies. Exposing the PHP methods as an API is something which has been done over to death, and a plethora of RESTful API frameworks exist to expedite the development of such applications. The same goes for C# applications/libraries consuming an API, provided you use something with a client implementation.

The answer to your question, "*Is it possible...*"; certainly yes, however this is a pretty high level requirement, and the implementation will rely completely on the problem domain.

---

As an elaboration (*might have been too long for a comment*) I'm currently working on a massive overhaul project. The previous developers decided to roll their own everything. What did that mean for me? I couldn't reuse an ounce of their code-base. They had rolled their own security strategies. Garbage.

I don't say garbage because I could **write** better (*I might, but not much*), but because I know better.

I favored well established technologies, ones that integrate well and have massive community and developer support. When I have a problem, between the docs and here, I can normally find a solution pretty quickly. Furthermore, issues with the components are documented, fixed, and can be worked around.

Rolling your own integral components (*be them security or otherwise*) for production, especially when you *know* you're treating it like a learning experience, is irresponsible.

Comment: The reasoning for needing to do this is the data contained within the database is personal information of minors. By not giving out permissions to the database the organization is trying to prevent unnecessary access to the data.

Yes, I figured there were APIs available for something like this. Though, you are not learning anything if you always rely on 3rd Party APIs. I've always tried to do it on my own the first time then any time after that I've either created my own API or I've used a 3rd Party API.

Comment: @RandomlyKnighted If you're working on a project that involves personally identifiable information of minors, I wouldn't even think about rolling my own anything for the sake of learning. Save that for a personal project; use well established tech for this one.